# CollectionView dose not show content, when filled in onappearing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `collectionview` that is bound to an `ObservableRangeCollection`in my ViewModel.

In my ViewModel there is a Method that runs onAppearing and I want my `ColletionView`to be filled from there, but when I do so the `collectionveiw` dose not display the content only when i reload the content is shown.

View:

```
<RefreshView Grid.Row="1"
                         Grid.RowSpan="2"
                         Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
                         IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}">
                <RefreshView.RefreshColor>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="White"/>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </RefreshView.RefreshColor>
                <CollectionView x:Name="Collection"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Locations, Mode=OneWay}"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListDataTemplate}"
                                RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreCommand}"
                                RemainingItemsThreshold="10"
                                SelectionMode="Single"  
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                                SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectedCommand}">
                    <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                        <StackLayout Padding="12">
                            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Keine Daten vorhanden!" TextColor="White"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </CollectionView.EmptyView>
                </CollectionView>
            </RefreshView>
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace YourPartys.ViewModels
{
    public class ListViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Variables

        #endregion

        #region Propertys
        LocationModel selectedItem;
        public LocationModel SelectedItem
        {
            get => selectedItem;
            set => SetProperty(ref selectedItem, value);
        }

        public ObservableRangeCollection<LocationModel> Locations { get;set; } = new ObservableRangeCollection<LocationModel>();

        double distance;
        public double Distance
        {
            get => distance;
            set => SetProperty(ref distance, value);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Commands
        public ICommand FilterButtonCommand { get; }
        public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; }
        public ICommand SelectedCommand { get; }
        public ICommand LoadMoreCommand { get; }
        #endregion

        //Constructor
        public ListViewModel()
        {
            FilterButtonCommand = new Command(OpenFilter);
            RefreshCommand = new AsyncCommand(Refresh);
            SelectedCommand = new AsyncCommand(Select);

            
        }

        public override async void VModelActive(Page sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            base.VModelActive(sender, eventArgs);

            var locs = await FirestoreService.GetLocations("Locations");
            Locations.AddRange(locs);
        }

        private void OpenFilter(object obj)
        {
            PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new ListFilterPage());
        }

        private async Task Refresh()
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            var locs = await FirestoreService.GetLocations("Locations");
            Locations.AddRange(locs);

            IsBusy = false;
        }

        private async Task Select()
        {
            if (SelectedItem == null)
                return;

            var route = $"{nameof(DetailPage)}?Locationid={SelectedItem.Locationid}";
            SelectedItem = null;
            await AppShell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What code runs in OnAppearing? Try wrapping it in `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( async () => { ... } );`.

Comment: Based on your code , I did a test,but I couldn't reproduce this problem, could you please post more code snippets or a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can help you better?

Comment: https://github.com/Crey443/Collectionview_test
I created this app and it has the same Problem

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your demo.

1.Since you set the `BindingContext`  for your page in xaml as follows:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:MainViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

you didn't need to recreate another object `MainViewModel` in a CS file and reference it. These are two different objects.

```
MainViewModel viewModel;
viewModel = new MainViewModel();

protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        viewModel.VModelActive(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

So, you can get the  `BindingContext` in `MainPage.xaml.cs` in function `OnAppearing` as follows:

```
      protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        viewModel = (MainViewModel)this.BindingContext;

        viewModel.VModelActive(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

The whole code is

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    MainViewModel viewModel;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       // viewModel = new MainViewModel();

    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        viewModel = (MainViewModel)this.BindingContext;

        viewModel.VModelActive(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

2.when we set the text color  of the Label to `White`,this makes it hard to see the text,so you can reset it to another color,for example `Black`:

```
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                      FontSize="30"
                                   TextColor="White"/>
```

Comment: Hi @Jeremiah, just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.